# Are there any hidden php right permission using imagejpeg() or in apache & php in general? Getting Unable to open Permission denied

Tags: php, apache

I am getting Unable to open ...  for writing: Permission denied when I try and resize an image.  The code has worked fine for years but after a resent upgrade (I think ) It has stopped working.  I have tried changing the permission on the folder to 777 and disabled selunix. Is there any thing that may have changed in my httpd.con file or php.ini file that will disabled a php script right?

The error message from Apache logs:

`[Mon Jun 25 08:59:17 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  imagejpeg(): Unable to open './cache/150_112.5_be636f82ef8e7e22727c81980df16cd5.jpg' for writing: Permission denied in /var/www/html/resize_function.php on line 62, referer: http://jasonrmoore.info/list.php?dir=./`

Answer (score 0):

Nop, this is an unix permission issue.

Please check the permission of the permissions of `./cache` folder and inner files.